# Angular Http GET call pass array as params to API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

Hi I'm new to angular hence got stuck at one place. I need to pass array as parameters to backend API
backend API expects array of string as parameters

```
 const params = new HttpParams();
 const depKey = ['deploymentInprogress', 'deploymentMessage'];
 params.append('depKey', JSON.stringify(depKey));

 this.http.get(uri, { params: params })
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError((error) => {
          return throwError(error);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => {

   })
```

The above code didn't work
Need an help on this I'm not sure how we can pass array of strings as params to our backend API

Comment: What means "didn't work"? What specifically didn't work? You are not passing an array, but a JSON-String that represents your array. It's hard to give any specific answer if we don't know how your backend expectes this data.

Comment: backend expects array of string. How can we pass the params as array of string?

Comment: Your API should be `POST` method to receive complex values such as objects/arrays. `GET` method for API only supports *simple value* via the query string, and query params.

Comment: @YongShun ok can you provide me the exact snippet using above params?

Comment: Signature of GET says we can pass array of stings   get(url: string, options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };

Comment: @MeenaPanchal "backend expects array of string" doesn't contain the information we need for a proper answer. _How_ does the backend expect the data? As part query parameter? As form data? Maybe in the request body? Maybe hidden in a request header? There are many ways to pass data to an backend. I believe you just choose a method of data transfer that your backend doesn't expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const params = new HttpParams();
 const depKey = ['deploymentInprogress', 'deploymentMessage'];
 params.append('depKey', depKey.join(', ');

 this.http.get(uri, { params: params }).....
```

Comment: The term "body" is misleading here. A `GET` requests isn't supposed to have a body and angular doesn't give you the option to pass one with `.get()`.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I copied and pasted without realizing it was a get.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the array values individually with the same parameter name, then api can read the individual values!

```
 const params = new HttpParams();
 const depKey = ['deploymentInprogress', 'deploymentMessage'];
 depKey.forEach((item: any) => {
     params.append('depKey', item);
 });

 this.http.get(uri, { params: params })
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        catchError((error) => {
          return throwError(error);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => {

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the specification of the backend API is. Without the specification it's just guessing how to get this to work.

Most of the times it will be encoded in the body and that can be done in may forms, for example:

```
{ 
   "key": "value",
   "items": [
      {"aaa":"bbb","ccc":"dddd"},
      {"aaa":"fff","ccc":"hhhh"}
   ]
}
```

but note: this is just one way of doing it!

If you can share your specifications, we can help you.

Maybe you have a postman example on how to call the endpoint?